# canvas can not be loaded by loadFromJSON() with group in canvas

Tags: json, fabricjs

My canvas includes a group, but when I want to save the canvas and put them to JSON, json can not be loaded correctly by loadFromJSON() mothod, and canvas is empty.

But,if my canvas do not include a group, yet includes text, image, json can be loaded correctly!

Can you help me?

My demo is the link: http://www.yinjoin.com/abc/d.htm